# Weird request to NodeJS Webserver

Tags: webserver

So logging all the requests I get things like this:

Mon Sep 07 2015 21:30:04 GMT+0200 (CEST) Received request for http://testp4.pospr.waw.pl/testproxy.php

also for http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.9927029395516237

My simple server:

```
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Received request for ' + request.url);
    response.writeHead(404);
    response.end();
});
```

Should I worry? What could that be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're seeing is an "open proxy" test: your webserver is being scanned to see if it can be used as a general-purpose HTTP proxy.

The requests are not something to worry about in and of themselves, but they reveal a weakness in your server: you're not logging what response the server makes to the request.  It should be a "404 not found", but you don't have the log entries to prove it.

Comment: @mark I also have a node.js server that appears to receive GET requests for zc.qq.com, `GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/chs/numreg/init?`, and my server appears to respond with a 200 status code.  I'm a bit confused as to how it can receive a request for a domain that it doesn't serve and how it is responding with a 200 status code.  Any thoughts most welcome, thanks.

Comment: @iss42 Check if you have a default host serving any name such as `<VirtualHost *:80>`. You may also try to access `http://`(server ip address)`cgi-bin/chs/numreg/init?` and see if that serves you content or an error

Comment: @iss42, it's not a request for a page named `/cgi-bin/chs/numreg/init` on `zc.qq.com`, it's a request for a local page named `http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/chs/numreg/init`.  Your server is probably configured to return a generic page (such as the root page or a site index) when the requested page does not exist, rather than a 404 error.